# Control Computer Fans Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, hardware

Does anyone know of any way to programmatically control the RPMs of a Mac's fans? I briefly checked the Apple Dev site, but couldn't find anything. I'm guessing it's not as easy as:

```
[fans faster];
```

I'm wondering how [smcFanControl](http://www.eidac.de/?p=207) achieves this. Am I right to assume that the "smc" in "smcFanControl" stands for System Management Controller?

**Update:**
smcFanControl source code is released under GLP license! ^_^ Oh, yeah! Free knowledge!

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/jsz/mbpfand. A simple fan speed control demon for Linux + Apple Mac Book Pro (5,5).The demon is written in Go and requires Go 1

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need to control the fan speed?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct on two counts: SMC does stand for "System Management Controller", and fooling around with it isn't as simple as [fans faster].  Programming the SMC requires knowledge of the firmware and some down-and-dirty hardware device driver programming.  You probably have to talk to the manufacturer just to get the specs, and if you do, you're not going to be able to program it in Objective C.  Alas, you're probably better off trying to control smcFanControl using AppleScript :)

Answer (score 0):

this answer may not able to help. I don't have Mac so I don't know how it works, just tell some basics.
Generally, a computer FAN speed control is handled by SuperIO chip or BMC(bus management controller) chip. 
if ur board using a SuperIO, then it is very hard to modify the FAN speed since the speed adjustment algorithm is fixed (fused) inside the chip.
if the board using BMC or similar solution, it will use Firmware to control the speed. most the firmware is upgrade-able by special tool.
above solutions will provide hardware level fan speed control, but the OS level can not change the speed.

I suppose the smcFancontrol in Mac is not a command to change the FAN speed, but able to enable "smart FAN speed control" function.